# Mongoose query always returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to make a greater than query but it always returns an empty array.

```
    const productSchema = require("./productsSchema");
const getProductsGreaterThan = async (minimum_id) => {
try{
    console.log(minimum_id);
    const productById = await productSchema.find({id: {$gt:minimum_id}});
    return productById
}
catch(err){
    console.error(err);
}
}
```

This is my controller:

```
if (req.params.minimum_id) {
    const productsById = await productsModel.getProductsGreaterThan(req.params.minimum_id);
    res.status(200).json(productsById);
}
```

It should return the products with an ID greater than what i type in the req.params...

```
routes.get("/products/:minimum_id?",productRoutes.getProductsGreaterThan);
```

But when i write the route like this in the url it gives me an empty array => http://localhost:3000/products/10  What is wrong with this code? Im very confused, because other queries like find({}) work. My mongoose version is 6.2.10.

Comment: Have you tried `const productById = await productSchema.find({id: {$gt:parseInt(minimum_id, 10)}});`?

Comment: I just tried, but its not working :(  It gives me an empty string aswell

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide your sample dataset. A common error is filtering on incorrect field, such as filtering on `id` instead of `_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Somehow the problem was in the name of the collection of mongoDB. It seems it should be always in lower-case and plural.

Comment: Thank you ! I was scratching my head for hours about this one !

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by changing MongoDB table name. The problem was in the name of the collection of mongoDB. Your table names should be always in lower-case and plural (this was most critical thing in my case). Maybe you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose and MongoDB the correct `id` format is `_id`.
So you would do the following:

```
productSchema.find({_id: {$gt:minimum_id}})
```

Comment: Yeah, but that id is one I put in the Schema. Not the authomatic one.